# call method from activity in all fragment instance

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have **PengaduanHomeActivity.class** with 3 tabs using same Fragment **PengaduanFragment.class** like here :

```
   public class PengaduanHomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

    ....

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.detail_profile_user);

            appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);

            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(7);

            mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

            appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);

        }

int index = 0;

@Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
    index = i;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            if (index == 0) {
                PengaduanFragment.enableRefreshLayout(true);
            } else {
                PengaduanFragment.enableRefreshLayout(false);
            }

            break;
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}


public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    private final String[] TITLES =
            {"News Task", "Task On Progress", "Completed Task"};
    private Bundle bundle;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return PengaduanFragment.newInstance("0");
            case 1:
                return PengaduanFragment.newInstance("1");

            case 2:
                return PengaduanFragment.newInstance("2");
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

in code above, i call method in PengaduanFragment

```
public static void enableRefreshLayout(boolean b) {

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(b);
    }
```

but method just called in last **PengaduanFragment** with position 2. Other PengaduanFragment with position 0 or 1, not called. So how to Called method **enableRefreshLayout** in all Fragment ? thaks

Comment: You should tell the adapter which can then invoke it on all children. I'd advise putting that method in an interface then all the child fragments implement that interface so that you can just simply loop over the fragments in the adapter and call the method on each.

Comment: thanks answered ... :), hmm.. may you tell me with example code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an interface that declares the method you want to use:

```
public interface IMyInterface {
    public void myMethod();
}
```

Then, each fragment you have should implement this method:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements IMyInterface {
  //Fragment code

  public void myMethod() {
    //Method code
  }
}
```

Finally, make your adapter have a collection of this interface and loop over it when invoked by the activity

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
  //Collection of fragments
  Fragment[] fragments;

  //Adapter code

  public void invokeMe(){
    //Loop through each fragment
    if (fragment instanceof IMyInterface) {
      fragment.myMethod();
    }
  }
}
```

You should then be able to call `invokeMe` and have the adapter delegate to the right fragments the right behaviour. Just be careful of if the fragment instance is still active as per your settings on your `ViewPager`'s current offscreen limit (adjustable by calling `setOffscreenPageLimit()`)

Comment: What is the value of your offscreen page limit? Can you add a some log entries to confirm it is only being called in the last fragment, and did you implement the loop in the adapter?

Comment: mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(PagerAdapter.fragments.length);

in first fragment > mSwipeRefreshLayout is false
in second fragment > mSwipeRefreshLayout is false
in last fragment > mSwipeRefreshLayout

its look called in last fragment.

i create interface `enableSwipeRefreshLayout`

. And in this loop

`for( Fragment fragment : fragments ) {
                if (fragment instanceof enableSwipeRefreshLayout) {
                    ((enableSwipeRefreshLayout) fragment).enableSwipeRefreshLayout(b);
                }
            }`

Comment: Do you reset it to false in the `onResume` in the fragments?

Comment: Can you please mark answer as correct? Thank you. Edit: posted as you did it, sorry